# Why is my hero image not showing in the title like it should?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an image to show up behind my title "Strike A Chord" The image is under the hero image section. What am I missing?

Below is first my index.html file, and then the second is my styles.css file.

It was showing up before but after I added some more code it no longer will show and it is just blank behind my title.

also, if it looks funny and basic, I am a student following the book's instructions. I haven't learned the easy shortcuts yet.

EDIT: After removing [class="tab-desk"] from the div id of the hero image, the image shows back up but in the correct spot.

```css
/* CSS Reset */
body,
header,
nav,
main,
footer,
img,
h1,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

/* Style Rule for Images */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* style rule for mobile view port */

/*hide tab-desk class */
.tab-desk {
  display: none;
}
/* set rules for header content */
header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #373684;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: "DM Serif Display", serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 4%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

/* Style rules for navigation area */
nav {
  background-color: #373684;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav li {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e9fc;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Styles Rule for main content */
main {
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: #e5e9fc;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
main p {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.action {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  color: #373684;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#piano,
#guitar,
#violin {
  margin: 0 2%;
}
#info {
  clear: left;
  background-color: #c0caf7;
  padding: 1% 2%;
}
#info ul {
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.round {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
#contact {
  text-align: center;
}
.tel-link {
  background-color: #373684;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.tel-link a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: block;
}

#contact .email-link {
  color: #4645a8;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.map {
  border: 5px solid #373684;
  width: 95%;
  height: 50%;
}

/* Style rules for footer content */
footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  clear: left;
}
footer a {
  color: #4645a8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!--Hero Image-->
<div id="hero" class="tab-desk">
  <img src="images/music-notes.png" alt="colorful music notes" />
</div>
```

Comment: We don't need your whole codebase, just enough to demonstrate the problem. That said this is probably a path issue.

Comment: Okay, I will edit it, sorry, I have only posted on here a few times before. I figured the more code to look at would be better to understand the problem But it is not a pathing issue, pathing is correct as it worked before I did any work today, I hope that looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS code you have the following property:

```
.tab-desk {
    display: none;
}
```

This is what is causing your `.tab-desk` (hero image) to not load. To fix your issue, you can either remove the aforementioned 3 CSS lines or remove the `class="tab-desk"` from:

```
<div id="hero" class="tab-desk">
    <img src="images/music-notes.png" alt="colorful music notes" />
</div>
```

Whichever one suits you best.

Comment: Thank you! That did partially solve the issue, right before I saw this comment I removed the class="tab-desk" from the code, but via the book I am supposed to have that in there and have the display set to none. Maybe it will be fixed later in the book. Thank you for pointing this out though, I can keep an eye on it as I continue!

Comment: Thank you for marking my answer as correct for others who face a similar issue to also know how to solve it. My guess for why it is in the book is probably to demonstrate how you can hide specific elements using the display: none; property.

Comment: Thats what I am thinking, I think I am currently setting up the mobile view and it will allow me to switch it later. after looking at a GitHub for this project, I saw that more is added to show tablet/dekstop view.